# validate form date filed in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JS date format and date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481353/js-date-format-and-date-comparison)

I have this javascript and i want to write code to make sure the date is in the future.
the format of the date is like this

dd/mmm/yyyy eg. 24-NOV-2012

```
var date = $j('#date').val();

if(date =='' || date is not a date in the future){  
dateError = 1;
}
```

Comment: And also not post the same question twice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481353/js-date-format-and-date-comparison

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new Date("24-NOV-2012") < new Date()
```

Comment: im getting an invalid date for the new Date("24-NOV-2012")